# How to configure bugzilla to not advance to next bug when updating?

Tags: configuration, bugzilla

By default, when you apply changes to a Bugzilla entry, the web interface advances to the next bug in your list.

I would like to disable this feature since it is almost never what I desire, planning to make further updates later.  Further, I often update the wrong bug subsequently due to its changing the current bug without my noticing.

How do I configure Bugzilla to not advance like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the "Preferences" link on the home page, and look for "After changing a bug".  Regardless of the site default, you can set your personal preference to "show next bug in my list," "show the updated bug," or "do nothing."

That's the way to do it on bugzilla.mozilla.org, which is at Bugzilla 3.4.6.  Depending on what version you're using, the exact link and wording may be a little bit different.  But it's the same general idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you are an admin you can set the site default on the "Default Preferences" page.

"After changing a ticket" - do nothing, show the next ticket or show the updated ticket.